# Как сравнить данные в списках по языковому признаку?

Tags: c#

Есть `6` строк в списке. Я хочу удалить `русскоязычную` версию фамилии, и оставить `украиноязычную`.

```
[0]: "ЛУК'ЯНЮК МИКОЛА ВОЛОДИМИРОВИЧ"
[1]: "ТАРАСЮК ОКСАНА АНАТОЛІЇВНА"
[2]: "ТАРАСЮК ОЛЕКСАНДР ІВАНОВИЧ"
[3]: "ЛУКьЯНЮК МИКОЛА ВОЛОДИМИРОВИЧ"
[4]: "ТАРАСЮК ОКСАНА АНАТОЛИИВНА"
[5]: "ТАРАСЮК ОЛЕКСАНДР ИВАНОВИЧ"
```

Сравнить две строки я могу через расстояние Левенштейна(Хемиинга), но не могу понять как понять на каком языке строка.

```
public static class StringDistance
    {
        public static int GetHammingDistance(string s, string t)
        {
            if (s.Length != t.Length)
            {
                throw new Exception("Strings must be equal length");
            }

            int distance =
                s.ToCharArray()
                .Zip(t.ToCharArray(), (c1, c2) => new { c1, c2 })
                .Count(m => m.c1 != m.c2);

            return distance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ну так в общем случае это не возможно, так как может попасть вариант, когда и русское и украинское написание совпадает

Comment: @Grundy ну если они совпадают тогда оставляем одно значение через Distinct

Comment: @Grundy я хочу пройтись по списку и отсеить похожие значения

Comment: Тут вообще нет русскоязычных записей, есть только транслитерированные из украинского в русский. PS. Интересно, а есть стандарт такой транслитерации? или все лепят как придётся?

Comment: @Akina _а есть стандарт такой транслитерации?_ по идее должны быть правила транслитерации, и даже несколько стандартов, например [ISO 9](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9)

Comment: *не могу понять как понять на каком языке строка.* В простейшем варианте - разве что выделить явно не-русские строки (содержат символы, не являющиеся кириллицей). Потом можно разобрать такие строки на отдельные токены и пометить их как явно не-русские (содержат не-кириллицу) и потенциально не-русские (не содержат не-кириллицы). То же сделать с остальными записями. Обработать вручную, деля все токены на чисто русские, чисто не-русские и двойные. В дальнейшем пользоваться полученным словарём. Периодически его пополняя, когда попадаются отсутствующие, либо с неопределённым статусом, токены.

Comment: @Grundy Я имею в виду именно транслитерацию украинского в русский. Общие стандарты, не учитывающие язык и оперирующие только символами и их транслитерацией в кириллицу - есть, это я в курсе.

Comment: @Akina, напрямую может и не быть, но можно через латиницу, например

Comment: @Grundy Перевод из одного языка в другой через третий - тема не одной шутки... с транслитерацией тоже можно налететь, далеко не все стандарты предлагают безальтернативно-обратимые таблицы транслитерации...

Comment: Как вариант авторизуйтесь для использования API яндекс-переводчика. Они предоставляли 1 млн. символов в день и 20 млн. в месяц, и прогоняйте текст через них (например, переводить на украинский, или русский, и сравнивайте). Если работа разовая, или редкая - то это подойти может =)